# I have a column that contains comments. I need to substring the value between two know words. SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

for example 
The first know is Occurance Date: and the next word is Type.
Occurance Date: 10/14/2013 type: drug physician xyz

In this example I need the date 10/14/2013

this is the code I have so far

```
substring(shortnote,charindex('occurance date:', shortnote),charindex('type',shortnote) - charindex('occurance date:', shortnote) -len('type'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could base you entire logic on your beginning pattern and resolve this using `PATINDEX`.

Something like

```
DECLARE @VAR VARCHAR(100)
SET @VAR='asdfasdfasfasdfasfa asasfd Occurance Date: 10/14/2013 type: drug physician xyz'

DECLARE @Begin_Pattern VARCHAR(100)
SET @Begin_Pattern='Occurance Date: '    

SELECT SUBSTRING(@VAR,(PATINDEX('%Occurance Date: %',@VAR)+LEN(@Begin_Pattern)),11)
```

Comment: I just tried it and it worked perfect. What's the 11 for because I'm going to use the code for the same idea but different words

Comment: Well the 11 is number of Characters in the date piece `LEN('10/24/2013')`